# Translate current_time

Tags: date, translation, date-time, timezones

I have `current_time` in theme and it displays date like: `THURSDAY, NOVEMBER 10, 2016`. But I need to translate it to Persian. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `date_i18n` instead of `current_time`. For example:

```
echo date_i18n( 'Y. F j.',  strtotime( get_the_time( "Y-m-d" ) ) );
```

Comment: You've overcomplicated. :) `get_the_time('Y. F j.')` would be sufficient, it will take care of localization internally.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth looking at using something like `date_i18n`, which returns the date/time in a localised format

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n

To recreate the current_time format you showed in your example, you could use something like `date_i18n('l, F j, Y');`